# Передача sprite с одной сцены на другую Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

помогите решить проблему. Необходимо передать спрайт с объекта находящегося в магазине на объект, находящийся на другой сцене. То есть, при нажатии кнопки покупки спрайт передается на объект в другой сцене.

Comment: [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) или вообще запоминать через PlayerPrefs: `PlayerPrefs.SetString(your_sprite.ToString())`

Comment: а потом как считывать

Comment: Не, я ошибся. Это не очень подходит для PlayerPrefs. Лучше все же DontDestroyOnLoad. Так вам старый объект не удалится при загрузке новой

Comment: Что значит передать спрайт, если он не на цене а в ассетах/ресурсах и доступен в любой сцене...